# Get Distinct record count on document key mongodb spring template along with other where criteria

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I'm trying to get distinct count using spring mongoTemplate, it is neither giving any exception nor the output, need suggestions

```
long count = exampleRepository.countIdProductIdInAndLastModifiedDateGreaterThanEqualAndDistinctByUserId
             (productIdList,modifiedDate);
```

Also tried using Criteria --->

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.andOperator(Criteria.where("productId").in(productIdList),
                        Criteria.where("lastModifiedDate").gte(modifiedDate));
Query query = new Query(criteria);
long Count = (long) mongoTemplate.getCollection("exampleCollection").distinct("user_id",
query.getQueryObject()).size();
```

Tried many other ways but these two are best closed to my problem and clear too. 
**Also, please suggest which approach is better and fast in fetching data?** 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you post the code for `countIdProductIdInAndLastModifiedDateGreaterThanEqualAndDistinctByUserId`?

Comment: This is the template query declared under custom repository which is extending MongoRepository still
`public interface ExampleRepository extends MongoRepository<Example, String> 
{
Long countIdProductIdInAndLastModifiedDateGreaterThanEqualAndDistinctByUserId(List<String> productId, Date date);
}`

The above **Example class** contains all the fields which you are seeing in query mapped with fields of mongo collection.